# Max of 2 IID Uniforms and symmetry

Tags: probability

This is a question from a previous exam. It seems too easy for the high amount of points it was worth. I don't have the answer key. Critique my answers please?

> $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniform random variables with ranges (0,1) and (0,1). Define $W$ as the maximum of ($X$, $Y$): $W$=Max($X$,$Y$).
>
> 1. Compute $P(W\leq0.3)$

$P(W\leq0.3) = P(X\leq0.3)\cdot P(Y\leq0.3) = 0.09$

> 2. Compute $P(W=X)$

$0.5$ by symmetry

> 2. Compute $E[W]$

$\int_0^12w^2dw = \frac{2}{3}$

> 4. Compute $E[W|W=X]$

$\frac{2}{3}$ by symmetry and independence. I interpreted $W=X$ to mean the realized value of W is equal to the realized value of X. Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: You can get nicer spacing for conditional probabilities by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are all right, though your reasoning is a bit terse. For $E[W]$, it's not clear to me what you computed – I guess you took the cumulative distribution function from $1.$, differentiated it and integrated it with $w$? I don't see where you need independence in $4.$; I think the result follows from $3.$ simply by symmetry. Here and in $2.$, to be precise you need not only symmetry but also $P(X=Y)=0$. I think your interpretation of the notation $E[W\mid W=X]$ is correct.